# How to strench child elements in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have LinearLayout, and I am trying to make the child elements to be 100%.
so far I have this

```
[E1] [E2] [E3]
```

while I want them to be

```
[E1]  
[E2]  
[E3]
```

what properties should I change?? I tried several such as layout_width

Comment: What did you set layout_width = to? Try 'fill_parent'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set LinearLayout orientation to vertical

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

And make all elements fill parent.

Answer (score 2):

You should change orientation property of your LinearLayout to vertical